# How to use NotifyBuilder to check if camel route has been called

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to verify in tests that camel route was called n times. For that I wanted use NotifyBuilder for where I use matches method. My problem is that matches method of NotifyBuilder always returns false. To simplify the code I created minimal Spring Boot project but I still could not figure out why is it failing.

To give you exact information here is the full source of my application.

MyRouteBuilder.java:

```
package com.example.cameldemo;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("direct:start")
            .log("${body} - ${headers}");
    }
}
```

Application.java:

```
package com.example.cameldemo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.NotifyBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        CamelContext camelContext = context.getBean(CamelContext.class);
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.getBean(ProducerTemplate.class);

        NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext).fromRoute("direct:start").whenDone(1).create();

        producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", "Hello Camel", "MyHeader", 123);

        boolean matches = notify.matches(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("The message was processed by Camel: " + matches);
    }
}
```

And pom.xml just in case:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>camel-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with Apache Camel</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.11.3</camel.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run this program I see Hello Camel - {MyHeader=123} printed in console which means that camel route does execute. However NotifyBuilder does not register it for some reason. What do I do wrong? PS in my actual project I can't modify camel route so only this NotifyBuilder part can be modified. This is because we have rule that we dont change production code to get tests working and since NotifyBuilder is the only code that would be in tests it's what can be changed.

Comment: The [`.fromRoute(`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/notify-builder.html#_notifybuilder_api) method takes a route ID parameter, but you pass an endpoint URI.  You must invoke the `.from(` method if you want to specify the route by endpoint URI.